# Hide controls in sfsafariviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

```
let sfViewController  = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
sfViewController.delegate = self

self.ViewC!.present(sfViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

I am opening a SFSafariViewController in my app. But for the security issue I do not want the controls given by this view. This view is giving Actions like- Done, Refresh, Share, Open in Safari.

For My purpose I just want Action- Done. Rest other actions should not be visible to user. I am supporting ios 10.0 + . 
Atleast that toolbar should not be there.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You should use WKwebview instead with your custom buttons

Comment: That's we rejected because of js injection possiblity

Comment: What I want is that user should not open the url in their safari browser

Comment: wkwebview is good for your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You Can't customize SFSafariViewController .

Apple says:

> Important
>
> In accordance with App Store Review Guidelines, this view controller
>   must be used to visibly present information to users; the controller
>   may not be hidden or obscured by other views or layers. Additionally,
>   an app may not use SFSafariViewController to track users without their
>   knowledge and consent.

Lastly, indeed, you may use `WKWebView` instead for further customisation of your screen.

> If your app lets users view websites from anywhere on the Internet,
>   use the SFSafariViewController class. If your app customizes,
>   interacts with, or controls the display of web content, use the
>   WKWebView class.

Read doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller

Comment: Can you check this questions solution suggested? Can I do what that guy says? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146531/ios-9-hide-toolbar-at-bottom-of-web-page-loaded-via-sfsafariviewcontroller

Comment: it s just a workaround, will not work properly still you can try if you can take risk of rejecting your app